# Let author add field to metabox by pressing a button

Tags: customization, custom-field, metabox

I have added a custom metabox for authors where they can fill in a url to a source, which I can then use in my template.

In my `functions.php`

```
<?php
/* Add metaboxes (see below) */
function add_custom_metaboxes(){
    add_meta_box('source_post_metabox', 'Link to bron (optional)', 'output_source_metabox', 'post');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_metaboxes');

/* Save values of custom metaboxes on save */
function save_custom_metabox($post_id){

    if(!isset($_POST['source_post_metabox_nonce'])) :
        return;
    endif;

    if(!wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['source_post_metabox_nonce'], 'source_post_metabox')) :
        return;
    endif;

    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) :
        return;
    endif;

    if(!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) :
        return;
    endif;

    if ( isset( $_POST['source_post'] ) ) {
        $data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['source_post'] );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_post_source', $data );
    }

}
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_metabox');

function output_source_metabox($post){
    wp_nonce_field('source_post_metabox', 'source_post_metabox_nonce');
    $post_source = $post->_post_source;

    echo '<label for="source_post">';
    echo '<input type="text" id="source_post" name="source_post" value="'.$post_source.'" style="width: 80%;max-width: 720px;">';
    echo ' Source of your post</label>';
    echo '<p>Try to be as specific as possible. <br> E.g. <em>http://tweakers.net/nieuws/101372/ing-belgie-wil-betalingsgedrag-van-klanten-meer-gebruiken-voor-dienstverlening.html</em></p>';
}

?>
```

However, I want  to add the option to add multiple sources. I thought about it, and the most user-friendly seems to add a button that adds an input field to the metabox. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/23n6s717/

```
counter = 0;
$(".add-field").click(function() {
    counter++;
    $("#source_post").after('<input type="text" id="source_post_'+counter+'" name="source_post_'+counter+'" value="" style="width: 80%;max-width: 720px;">');
});
```

However, I don't know how I can "link" these new input fields to my back-end. How can I let Wordpress know that there are multiple fields that need to be accounted for, and saved? And how can I output all of them?

Comment: This is really just PHP and HTML. Use `source_post[]` and process the `$_POST` data as array.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Could you give me a hand putting that into code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I packed everything together. Consider using `wp_enqueue_script()` to use the script. With this code, you will save all URLs as an array. See how I use `get_post_meta()` to retrieve the saved URLs.

```
function save_custom_metabox($post_id){
    if(!isset($_POST['source_post_metabox_nonce'])) :
        return;
    endif;

    if(!wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['source_post_metabox_nonce'], 'source_post_metabox')) :
        return;
    endif;

    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) :
        return;
    endif;

    if(!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
        return;


    if ( isset( $_POST['source_post'] ) ) {
        foreach( $_POST['source_post'] as $key => $val )
            $_POST['source_post'][ $key ] = sanitize_text_field( $val );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_post_source', $_POST['source_post'] );
    }

}
add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_metabox');

function output_source_metabox($post){
    wp_nonce_field('source_post_metabox', 'source_post_metabox_nonce');
    $post_sources = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_post_source', true );
    if( is_array( $post_sources ) )
        foreach( $post_sources as $post_source )
            echo '<input type="text" id="source_post" name="source_post[]" value="'.$post_source.'" style="width: 80%;max-width: 720px;"><br />';
    else
        echo '<input type="text" id="source_post" name="source_post[]" value="" style="width: 80%;max-width: 720px;"><br />';
    echo '<button class="add-field">+</button>';
    echo '<p>Try to be as specific as possible. <br> E.g. <em>http://tweakers.net/nieuws/101372/ing-belgie-wil-betalingsgedrag-van-klanten-meer-gebruiken-voor-dienstverlening.html</em></p>';
    echo '<script>counter = 0;
jQuery(".add-field").click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    jQuery("#source_post").after(\'<input type="text" id="source_post_\'+counter+\'" name="source_post[]" value="" style="width: 80%;max-width: 720px;">\');
});</script>';
}
```

### Usage in template files

You can output these URLs in template files like this:

```
<?php
//We expect $post_sources to be an array
$post_sources = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_post_source', true );
if( ! empty( $post_sources ) && count( $post_sources ) > 0 ):
    //Output all sources as a list if sources exist
    ?>
    <ul><?php
    foreach( $post_sources as $post_source ):
    ?>
        <li><?php echo $post_source; ?></li>
    <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;


if( isset( $post_sources[ 0 ] ) ):
    //Output only a single source, in this case the first one
    ?>
    <p><?php echo $post_sources[ 0 ]; ?></p>
    <?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising! (Not tested yet.) Could you give an example how I would output this in a template file? Only one element from the array, as well as all of them?

Comment: updated my answer :)

Comment: Does this mean that you only need one nonce field per metabox? I always thought you would need one per input field?

Comment: One is enough :)